# Spring MVC, checking the @SessionAttributes content before and after status.setComplete()

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3, spring-4

For research and testing purposes

I have the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/deportista")
@SessionAttributes(value={"deportistaRegistrar", "deportistaActualizar", "collections"})
public class DeportistaController {
```

The values for each key assigned in `@SessionAttributes` are populated later

I want to know how I can check the data saved in the Spring Session through `@SessionAttributes`

I have tried

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/actualizar.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String actualizarPerson(@Validated @ModelAttribute("deportistaActualizar")   Deportista deportista, 
                           BindingResult result,
                           SessionStatus status,
                           HttpSession session){

    ...
    logger.info("actualizarPerson - Before status.setComplete();");
    checkHttpSession(session);
    status.setComplete();
    logger.info("actualizarPerson - After status.setComplete();");
    checkHttpSession(session);
    ...

}

private void checkHttpSession(HttpSession session){

    logger.info("checkHttpSession");

      Enumeration<String> enumSession = session.getAttributeNames();
      while (enumSession.hasMoreElements()) {
        String attributeName = enumSession.nextElement();
        logger.info("{}", attributeName);
        Object object = session.getAttribute(attributeName);
        if(object==null)
            logger.info("{} is null", attributeName);
        else
            logger.info("{} is NOT null", attributeName);
      }     
}
```

Even when `status.setComplete();` has been called or executed I can see the same keys and the values how not null or deleted, practically the same result prior to call the `status.setComplete();`. So, something is missing or wrong.

For research and testing purposes how I could see the keys/data before and after the `status.setComplete();` execution? Of course if is after the `status.setComplete();` should be empty or not exists, and it is not happening how is expected.

I have read how *reference* the following:
[Understanding Spring MVC Model and Session Attributes](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javadoc for `SessionStatus`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/SessionStatus.html) states

> Simple interface that can be injected into handler methods, allowing
>   them to signal that their session processing is complete. **The
>   handler invoker may then follow up** with appropriate cleanup, [...]

`SessionStatus` does not actually have any link to the underlying `HttpSession`. It just acts as a flag. The component that invoked your handler method, passing in the `SessionStatus` argument, will, after the invocation, check the `SessionStatus` and remove attributes if required.

Comment: Just what I've thought. It is handled by Spring after to completed the execution of the handler method